# How to enable debug level for logs for gitlab services in kubernetes executor

Tags: docker, debugging, kubernetes, gitlab, runner

gitlab omnibus 13.9.3 (ea359c58edb) runner installed as kubernetes executor in EKS with helm. Log level in runner set to debug.

[image]

my gitlab ci job(docker build with downloading a big file 1.5Gb and extracting it with 7zip to 4.6Gb) is broken with 137 error. Smth external force killed container..

[image]

the job itself:

[image]
I wish to know why and go to kubernetes and show logs. There are 3 containers for every CI job: build, helper and svc-0. Logs present only in svc-0(docker:dind service) and I can the cause of 137 error:

```
time="2021-03-25T09:26:10.955462192Z" level=info msg="Layer sha256:ae010d7db881545a9cbe2ebb0740b623de2de8a50dc5b8baba28f4d33c699f5d cleaned up"
time="2021-03-25T09:26:11.063293745Z" level=info msg="shim containerd-shim started" address=/containerd-shim/7b7fc67d4b559d544c1735fcd5d48c3a4748844f31a7f634c4eeabe4daec9a29.sock debug=false pid=1403
time="2021-03-25T09:32:55.037821515Z" level=info msg="Processing signal 'terminated'"
```

We can see here that logs is not in debug level and I have no idea how to turn it on. I tried to found some variable or smth to add to gitlab-runner config, but have no luck with it.
I checked k8s limits for CPU and memory, I checked free disk space with `df -h`... all is OK.

[image: gitlab.toml configuration for runner]

also found that we can configure services in config.toml too, but cannot find how to enable logs here too...
[image]

My main question is: How to understand why docker container with my job dies?
And the question that will help me to investigate the answer for question above is: How to enable debug logs for gitlab runner services(especially for docker:dind)?

EDITED. I figured out the solution. The answer is in my error code: 137. This Pod was killed by OOM. I just increased memory request\limit and it works fine now.
log_level = "debug" in ~/.gitlab-runner/config.toml works fine.